# Java - Canvas fica piscando ao redesenhar a tela

Tags: java, swing, canvas

Estou fazendo uma aplicação gráfica com a classe **Component**, mas sempre que eu apago a tela para desenhar um novo quadro, o Canvas pisca!

A função clearBackground:

```
public void clearBackground() {
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

**background** é a cor branca, mas ele pisca, e eu já fiz de tudo para resolver o problema, mas sempre que ele renderiza, o Canvas pisca, mas as vezes ele permanece sem piscar, e logo depois volta! O que eu posso fazer para resolver o problema?

Comment: Você está desenhando dentro de um JPainel ao invés de desenhar direto dentro de um JFrame?

Comment: Não. Eu utilizei somente a função add(screen), onde screen é o Canvas. O que você quer dizer é adicionar no contentPane do JFrame?

Comment: "myFrame.add(myPanel)" onde myFrame é um JFrame e myPanel é um JPanel, aí você desenha no JPanel, tenta isso.

Answer (score -1):

O meu estava com o mesmo erro entao revisei a ordem de altura e largura por exemplo:

```
public static int WIDHT = 240;

public static int HEIGHT = 120; 

public static int SCALE = 3;
```

public BufferedImage layer = new BufferedImage(WIDHT*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

public Game() {
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDHT*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));